# Using Truncate in SQL Server from MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I've spent several days on this issue, major research and lot's of trial and error attempts to find a solution.  Here is what I have and what I need to make work:

1. Sproc in SQL Server 2008 that calls: TRUNCATE TABLE tablename (30,000 records)
2. MS Access (2010) Client
3. A Batch file that uses SQLCMD Utility to call the Stored Procedure

Within my Access client, I am using vba/Shell() method to call the Batch file.
The batch file then uses SQLCMD to connect to SQL Server and call the SPROC.

If I click on the batch file directly from my machine, it works perfect, 2 seconds max.
If I run the batch file from within Access using Shell() method, it seems to be treating the TRUNCATE in my SPROC as a DELETE instead of TRUNCATE.  It sits idle for several minutes and times out, no records get deleted.

If I do the same on a table with only a few thousand records it succeeds, about 5 seconds.

I know, "don't use Access as a client"!  I inherited this app from Non-IT so I have to make it work, no funds to re-architect it.

I have not posted here in ages, so hope I'm fowllowing protocol,

Thanks for any potential solutions in advance,

Comment: I think you'd be better off executing the SQL statement directly as a passthrough query, or by calling the stored procedure through a passthrough query.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server and profile it? Are you certain the batch file is being executed completely via the shell?  I would use logging (both profile, resource monitoring, and batch text output logging) to determine where the hold up is.

Comment: Have you looked into executing the procedure via an `ADO Command`?

Comment: Truncate and Delete are two very separate operations. I can assure you that it is not somehow changed into a delete operation by Access. It is probably timing out due to some sort of lock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up an on demand job in the SQL Server Agent that calls the sproc? You can then just run the job with a t-sql command.

Comment: Executing the SQL statement directly through a pass-through query I tried several ways with no luck.  Yes, the batch file is being executed becasuse it works perfectly when there are just a few thousand records, but times out after about 2 minutes on 10,000+ records. It seems that the wire from Access opening the batch file (I suspect in the same process space) takes control over the SQL Server Sproc's behavior, as if it's forcing it to run as a DELETE and NOT Truncate. I am using in the Sproc an account with full perms; (WITH EXECUTE AS Account)